# Change color of text if value becomes > original value, Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div class="Value">
    <em id="ProductPrice" class="ProductPrice VariationProductPrice">$83.00</em>
</div>
```

I need a script that changes the color of the price value to red if it changes.

I started with this:

```
 var original_value = $("#ProductPrice").text()
 if ($("#ProductPrice").text() > original_value) {
 $("#ProductPrice").css("color","red");
 }
```

It doesn't work at all, but I don't get any errors.
Also the price value is set by a variable and can change based on what page it is on.
Any input is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well... what your code is saying is basically "x is y. now, is y greater than x?"

Comment: you're getting the text twice in a row, so it's always going to be exactly the same!

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings, not numbers. Convert your string to a number.

Basic idea to get the number:

```
var str = "$12.23";
var muNumber = parseFloat(str.replace("$",""));
```

Comment: He's executing them instantaneously. There's no onchange.

Comment: @Jonathan The OP is comparing strings, my answer is still right on that point.

Comment: @Jonathan feel free to add an answer with the onchange and the defaultValue. ;)